# Best language to manipulate sound?

Tags: audio

I would like to make an "simple" program that after i clap the hands would do an certain event like open a browser. However i want do other things after this, so the program must be able to evolve.

Which programing languague should i choose in order to do this?

I know vb, python, c, c++, learning java(isnt going very well).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I just don't *believe* that you 'know' vb, python, c, and c++. Because if you did - you'd know that all you have to do to is google the problem, and you'd find a solution for *multiple* different languages.

I think instead of trying to jump into a 'clap detection app', a better idea would be to start slowly and actually MASTER (or at least start trying to master) one language. A jack of all trades is a master of none - and this is especially true in beginning programming. Just dive into one of the languages you 'know', I'd suggest Python due to its general user-friendliness and diverse supporting libraries. Just keep learning and eventually you'll be able to do almost anything!

Comment: I did face dectetion whit python, a kind of high efficient algorithm whit vb.net. I dont think i should be called Master but i think i can say that i know how to "get the job done". However i have no ideia how can i transform an sound into data. No matter the language i try to use, i never worked whit the sound before.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give a simple, non-opinion based answer. A programming language serves two purposes:

> "it provides a vehicle for the programmer to specify actions to be executed,
>
> it provides a set of concepts for the programmer to use when thinking about what can be done."

(Bjarne Stroustrup: "C++ programming language, 1.3.2.)

Your problem is not simple at all - *clap detection* is not a trivial thing to do: it involves real-time detection of a time characteristic, spectral characteristic and possibly a visual gesture (not to be confused with a similar sound from a different source). Take into account that a clap from the same person in different spaces also sounds differently. Take into account possible dynamic variations.

Only by learning languages in depth you'll be able to get familiar with language specific *concepts for the programmer to use when thinking about what can be done*, as well as with *specifying actions to be executed* for any particular language.

Also, when dealing with sound, you need a basic knowledge of acoustics.

As a rule of thumb, almost all serious real-time audio processing code is written in languages which are **mature**, **small** and can make **fast** runtime executables.

Comment: I realy liked your answer, in order to solve the problem of "accuracy", the clap action would be recorded for just one person, me. The ideia of confirm by visualising isnt bad at all, it didnt occured me before(nice), but i will not use it anyway, it would be an waist of compilation time and more work for me. However i didnt got an straight answer.